# What is the java signal dispatcher thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was looking through a thread dump of a java process, and notice some threads blocked by signal dispatcher.

What is signal dispatcher?  What does it do?

Answer (score 9):

I found an article about this on IBM developerWorks. When the OS raises a signal to the JVM, the signal dispatcher thread will pass the signal to the appropriate handler

[Revelations on Java signal handling and termination](https://web.archive.org/web/20090214230330/http://ibm.com:80/developerworks/java/library/i-signalhandling)
by Chris White, Software Engineer, IBM

Comment: The link is broken, seems it's been transcribed here: http://blog.intelligencecomputing.io/twitter/2348/revelations-on-java-signal-handling-and-termination

Comment: That link doesn't look any better.

Comment: @conorgriffin I can confirm that the link is also broken. I found the transcribed article on [blog.intelligenttime.net](http://blog.intelligenttime.net/java/2348/revelations-on-java-signal-handling-and-termination).

Answer (score 7):

OS Signals are inherently single-threaded, so it's important that they are all handled on the same thread.  So, a dispatcher is a natural way to achieve this.  Think of it like the single GUI event thread for AWT.

On a tangential note, if you are  Linux and your JVM loads a native library that inserts its own signal handlers, then you will need to preload [libjsig.so](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/vm/signal-chaining.html).  I found out the hard way when a third-party networking library intermittently tore down my connections with misdirected sigpipes.