# DestroyJavaVM thread ALWAYS running

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, java-threads

When profiling my application I came across a weird behavior - the DestroyJavaVM thread is ALWAYS running - 100% of the time.

[image]
After doing a little research on the subject, on which there's hardly any valuable information online, all I understood is that this thread is supposed to [unload the JVM upon exit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6437280/223365).

If that's the case, why is this thread in RUNNING state 100% of the time from the very first moment I start my application? Doesn't it consume valuable resources and therefore may cause an `OutOfMemoryError` (like I sometimes get)?

Is there any official reference to what this thread actually does and what triggers its initialization?

Thanks

Comment: It's more likely that other threads are causing the `OOME`. I wouldn't start with the least obvious suspect. Have you profiled your application threads for memory use? That would be the straight forward approach to debugging your mysterious `OOME`s.

Comment: 10x for the answer. Of course I used other measures to find why I get the OOME (which, BTW is a "GC Overhead Limit Exceeded" error, which is caused by a high CPU usage), but to no avail. This is kind of my last resort. This thread is very suspicious and I want to know what business it has running 100% of the time.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This happens because most applications are run in threads.

All [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) apps start by invoking the `main` method. In its most simple case, this method will do all of the work, creating objects, calling methods etc. Once `main` completes, the JVM is told to shut down using a `DestroyJavaVM` thread which waits for all [non-daemon threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-a-daemon-thread-in-java) to complete before doing its work. This is to ensure that any non-daemon threads you create run to completion before the JVM is torn down.

An app with a GUI, however, normally runs as a number of threads. One for watching for system events such as keyboard or mouse events. One for maintaining the windows and display etc. The `main` method of this kind of app will probably just start up all the required threads and exit. It still creates the `DestroyJavaVM` thread but now all that it does is wait for all of your created threads to finish before tearing down the VM.

As a result, any app that creates threads and relies solely on their functionality will always have a `DestroyJavaVM` thread waiting for it to finish. Since all it is doing is `join`ing all other running threads it does not consume any resources.

Comment: 10x for the answer.
My app doesn't have any GUI. I am instantiating a lot of threads, though, and surely rely on their functionality. Does it have anything to do with the DestroyJavaVM thread? What actually triggers its initialization?
If I understand you correctly, you say that even though the thread is shown as RUNNING, it's actually WAITING?

Comment: @KidCrippler - It is created and started after `main` exits. See [Thread.join()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.join%28long%29) for why it is in a `Running` state - it uses `wait(0)` in a tight loop.

Answer (score 0):

This barely scratches the surface.  It helps to recognize that there are System-triggered Quits and ForceQuits, and the app must know how to respond without being blocked indefinitely by non-daemon threads.

As a Java programmer, I need to know when the OS is telling the app to close down (so I can save the User's Work).